# CakePHP3 - Reflexive relation and finder

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, finder

I've start to develop a new website with CakePHP3 and i'm stuck on a relation.

Given the entity Movies and the Join Table MoviesMovies. Each Movie is in relation with other movies but without direction in the relation.

With CakePHP2, i used the property **finderQuery** in my relation definition :

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Movies' => array(
        'finderQuery' => 'SELECT movies.* FROM movies JOIN movies_movies ON (movies_movies.movie_1_id = movies.id AND movies_movies.movie_2_id = {$__cakeID__$}) OR (movies_movies.movie_2_id = movies.id AND movies_movies.movie_1_id = {$__cakeID__$})'
    )
);
```

I try to reproduce this behavior in CakePHP3 with the property **finder** but it doesn't work and there is no equivalent for *{$**cakeID**$}* :

```
$this->belongsToMany('Movies', [
    'finder' => 'relations'
]);

public function findRelations(Query $query, array $options){
    $query->join([
        'mm' => [
            'table' => 'movies_movies',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => [
                'OR' => [
                    'AND' => ['mm.movie_1_id = movies.id', 'mm.movie_2_id = {$__cakeID__$}'],
                    'AND' => ['mm.movie_2_id = movies.id', 'mm.movie_1_id = {$__cakeID__$}']
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    return $query;
}
```

Am I doing the right way ? And how do you code this custom finder ?

**PS** : problem with CakePHP2 is here [Reflexive many-to-many relationship in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370414/reflexive-many-to-many-relationship-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$this->belongsToMany('RelatedMovies', [
    'className' => 'Movies',
    'through' => 'movies_movies',
    'conditions' => [
         'OR' => [
                'AND' =>['MoviesMovies.movie_1_id = RelatedMovies.id', 'MoviesMovies.movie_2_id = Movies.id'],
                'AND' => ['MoviesMovies.movie_2_id = RelatedMovies.id', 'MoviesMovies.movie_1_id = Movies.id']
            ],
    ],
]);
```